# so far, so cold war

Tags: meaning

*In the broadest possible terms, then, this is the cold war all over again – implacable opposition, openly stated, with nowhere to go, no overarching authority to adjudicate, no sit-down, no road map, only hostility expressed by cultural, territorial or financial proxy. **So far, so cold war**.*

Is the emphasized part of the excerpt from the article from the Guardian some sort of a rhetoric figure? I am familiar with the phrase *so far so good*. Is the above phrase the form of it?

Comment: imo, it's a new coinage, expecting the reader to be familiar with 'so far, so good' & the myriad variations that have sprung from it, 'so far, so bad' being the obvious. P.S. I don't think it's a very good one.

Comment: Side note: The paragraph doesn't make much sense to me. "Cold war" is usually defined as a conflict characterized by spying, sabotage, and indirect conflict through proxies, as opposed to a direct clash of arms between the two sides. Pretty much all wars have "implacable opposition" and "no overarching authority to adjudicate", and many have "no road map", so I don't see how the writer's premise leads to his conclusion. But whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a play on the idiom, "so far, so good". I've never heard this particular phrase before -- I mean the writer's "so far, so cold war" -- so maybe the writer here invented it. In any case, it's not a common phrase by any means.

Comment: I agree that it is a play on "so far, so good". I do wonder whether it is also a play on "That is so (last year)", simultaneously indicating the retroness of Cold War hostilities.

Comment: @michelle Of course I can't say what the writer was thinking. If I wanted to convey that idea, I might say, "This is SO cold war". As the phrase as written doesn't fit that pattern, I doubt that's what he had in mind, but who can say?